# Find stdlib implementation on Linux at run-time

Tags: c++, linux

I'm writing a program that executes on Linux. How can I find an implementation of the C++ Standard Library programmatically *at run-time*? Pretty much all of the things I found with Google and whatnot were Bash commands, rather than C++ API calls. I need to both dynamically link to the implementation *and* find matching header search paths to include.

If there is none ready for use, that is user error- if there are multiple available e.g. multiple versions of libstdc++ or libc++ available, then ideally I'd choose the latest but any would be acceptable.

Comment: Why do you need headers at run-time?  You'll need the standard library that your program was compiled to run against, not some other version of the standard library.  Multiple versions are not guaranteed to be upwards or downwards compatible; attempting to use the wrong version may fail, or may produce unexpected results.

Comment: A normal Linux program starts with `libc` already loaded by `ld`. So do you mean that the program will *not* be linked to `libc` from the start and will have to use the Linux syscalls to find and link it?

Comment: The program invokes Clang as a library to JIT some C++, and I need the appropriate headers/libs for *that* C++, not the program itself.